# How do I work with grouped data in a 2 x 2 design?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm working on an experiment where participants are administered the Empathy Quotient (EQ), are randomized into one of two conditions, and then perform a memory task. So it's a 2 x 2 design. I'm trying to see whether the performance on the task differs between people with low and high EQ and if there's an interaction between EQ and the condition.

I divided the data into two groups based on their EQ scores:

```
low_EQ = subset(data, EQ < 21)
high_EQ = subset(data, EQ > 20)
```

I was able to compare the performance on the memory task across the two conditions without taking EQ into account -- I have two variables denoting the score on the memory task corresponding to each condition (score1 and score2).

Then I tried to see whether the scores on the memory task differ between the two groups, but I ended up getting null sets when I tried something along those lines:

```
low_EQ_score1 = low_EQ$score1
```

I hoped that this code would give me the recognition scores of people with low EQ who were in Condition 1, but it just gave me an empty set.

So I need four groups of scores in total: the scores of people in Condition 1 who have low EQ, people in Condition 1 who have high EQ, people in Condition 2 who have high EQ, and people in Condition 2 who have low EQ.

Is there any way I can get grouped data based on a 2 x 2 design?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: As mentioned, it would be helpful if you could provide both: (1) a sample of your data, editing your question with the result of `dput(head(data, 10))` for example, to show 10 rows of data; and (2) clarify what the desired result should look like (e.g., 4 rows of scores, 2 conditions, and 2 EQ groups)...you may not want to subset your data by `EQ`, instead, you can leave EQ in your `data`, add a column that would be the dichotomized equivalent (low/high), and include another column for condition...that is likely easier for analyses than multiple subgroups...